# WndProc capture shift+left mouse double click

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

Im trying to make my winforms app respond to Shift + double click left mouse button

Using WndProc

Any suggestions would be great!!

Comment: Why on Earth would you use WndProc?  Just implement the MouseDoubleClick event handler and check Control.Modifiers for the Shift key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
                {
                    if (Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift))
                    { 
                        //Shift plus mouse left button double clicked
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```